# Can't get an image to be the width I want it to be

Tags: css, reactjs

I want the image in the card to be 855px wide but I also want it to automatically resize to something smaller when the screen squeezes it. I've tried different combinations of flex-grow/flex-basis/align-items: strech/...etc applied to different classes, but nothing seemed to work.

I made sandbox with an example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-thompson-2itst

The code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Page">
        <div>
          <div className="Page--top">
            <p>
              Nullam nec imperdiet lorem, at imperdiet nulla. Pellentesque
              habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
              turpis egestas.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="Page--bottom">
            <div className="Page--left">
              <div className="Filters">
                <p>abcd1111</p>
                <p>abcd2222</p>
                <p>abcd3333</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="Page--right">
              <div className="Sort">
                <p>1111</p>
                <p>2222</p>
                <p>3333</p>
                <p>4444</p>
              </div>
              {new Array(4).fill(0).map(x => (
                <div className="Card--container">
                  <img
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/2TX2rmL.jpg"
                    alt="card pic"
                    className="Card--image"
                  />
                  <div className="Card--info">
                    <h1>abcde</h1>
                    <h2>12345</h2>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" className="Card--button">
                    xyz123
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
    "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans",
    "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.App {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* min-width: 100vw; */
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
  padding: 50px 90px;
}

.Page > * {
  background-color: red;
}

.Page--bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.Page--top,
.Page--left,
.Page--right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Page--left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.Page--right {
  align-items: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.Page--right > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.Page--top > * {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.Page--left > *:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.Page--left {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.Card--container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* flex-basis: 855px; */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 855px;
  max-height: 435px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "image image image image image"
    "info info info button button";
}

.Card--image {
  grid-area: image;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.Card--info {
  grid-area: info;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  align-self: center;
}

.Card--info > * {
  color: white;
}

.Card--button {
  grid-area: button;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.Filters {
  width: 315px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 30px;
}

.Filters > *:not(:last-child) {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ebe8e8;
}
.Filters > *:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.Sort {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.Sort > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 90px;
}

.Sort > *:not(:first-child) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the CSS:

```
img {
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything.

Comment: You need to add it to your selector for the image. I tested it on your .Card--image selector from your link, and it worked.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't have that there previously.

It looks like it's maintaining the same width of its container now, is that not what you wanted?

Do you want it to maintain both height and width?

Comment: I only care about width for now. I can't get it to be 855px.

Comment: By looking into it more, I noticed that the cat picture that is the img src is only 640 x 360, which means object-fit: contain will only get as wide as the 640 by default. To get the 855px, you would need to set it explicitly to width: 855px, and use object-fit: cover instead, but this will cause some of the image to become cut off because the image will conform to the size of the img tag instead of the source.